# On OSX Valgrind reports this memory leak, Where is it coming from?

Tags: c++, c, macos, memory-leaks, valgrind

On OSX Valgrind reports this memory leak, Where is it coming from? The code is c compiled with g++ as c++ code (i do this for function overloading).

```
==13088== 18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 82 of 264
==13088==    at 0x1F25DC: malloc_zone_malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:267)
==13088==    by 0xA1AEDA: malloc_set_zone_name (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==13088==    by 0xA1B4A7: _malloc_initialize (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==13088==    by 0xA1B5DD: malloc_good_size (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==13088==    by 0x4EFA6E: __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x4F3900: CFStringAppend (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x506F91: _convertToURLRepresentation (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x60F963: _CFURLInit (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x4FF268: CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPathRelativeToBase (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x4FF8EE: CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x515735: _CFBundleGetMainBundleAlreadyLocked (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x515663: CFBundleGetMainBundle (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x539533: cacheBundleInfo (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x5394B3: _CFAppVersionCheckLessThan (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x56C35B: __CFInitialize (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==13088==    by 0x8FE11243: ImageLoaderMachO::doImageInit(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE10CB3: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE0E21F: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE0E1B5: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE0F1BF: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE03655: dyld::initializeMainExecutable() (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE07EF1: dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE012EE: dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0x8FE01062: _dyld_start (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==13088==    by 0xFFF: ???
```

EDIT: also, how would I release this memory?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226691/valgrind-mac-os-mem-leak

Comment: Also possibly relevant: http://www.mail-archive.com/valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03053.html

Comment: @bames53 difference is that this leak is in the 'definitely lost' category, not 'still reachable'

Comment: Yes - this is 'definitely lost' memory, and that is a big difference.  But it is still outside your control; it is being allocated (and lost?) before your program gets properly started.  I would add it as a suppression without qualms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The allocation is completely out of your control; the free is likewise substantially impossible for you.  This should be added to the list of known, detected, recorded but ignored items ('suppressed' is the jargon).

When I run a program under valgrind 3.7.0 on MacOS X 10.7.2, I get a summary like:

```
==71989== 
==71989== HEAP SUMMARY:
==71989==     in use at exit: 6,191 bytes in 33 blocks
==71989==   total heap usage: 33 allocs, 0 frees, 6,191 bytes allocated
==71989== 
==71989== LEAK SUMMARY:
==71989==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==71989==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==71989==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==71989==    still reachable: 6,191 bytes in 33 blocks
==71989==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==71989== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==71989== 
==71989== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==71989== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

This is from a program that does no explicit memory allocation - `printf()` may trigger some allocation, but most of those bytes are allocated in system libraries.  You've clearly got a deeper than normal value set for the traceback (`--num-callers=N`).

Look in the manual for how to add a suppression record properly, but `valgrind --help` offers:

```
--num-callers=<number>    show <number> callers in stack traces [12]
--error-limit=no|yes      stop showing new errors if too many? [yes]
--error-exitcode=<number> exit code to return if errors found [0=disable]
--show-below-main=no|yes  continue stack traces below main() [no]
--suppressions=<filename> suppress errors described in <filename>
--gen-suppressions=no|yes|all    print suppressions for errors? [no]
```

So, you could get `valgrind` to generate the suppression string for you to add to a file which you then use in subsequent runs.

```
Extra options read from ~/.valgrindrc, $VALGRIND_OPTS, ./.valgrindrc
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like it's in one of the libraries you're using, if so then make sure you're using the library's API properly, but also know that sometimes a library allocates global resources, when initialized for example, which it doesn't not free until the program exits.

For example, consider this situation:

```
void init_lib(){
    static char *buf=NULL;
    if (buf==NULL) {
       buf = malloc(18);
    }
    .....
}
```

How can the library free this buffer before exiting? it can't, until the program exits and its memory is reclaimed by the OS.

See Common pitfalls [here](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/using-valgrind-to-debug-memory-leaks)

Edit: technically, in the above example, buf can be free'd as suggested by one of the comments below, but many libraries don't bother doing that because buf will be used for the duration of the program and the memory will be reclaimed when the program exits, so valgrind reports it as a memory leak.

Comment: The only library i use is SQLite. I do call its release functions, so i dont see how that could be the problem.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: you have a shutdown/cleanup call. Many libraries have that behaviour. However, as far as I know, SQLite does not. I think that osx's g++ is linking the core foundation libraries and adding an initialization call: `__CFInitialize`. How would I call the cleanup?

Comment: In your specific example, you cant get a reference to the pointer outside that function, but you can always have one global structure which keeps track of pointers that need to be released. Then go through the list on the cleanup call. You would then add the pointer to the list after the malloc call.

Comment: yes many libraries have clean-up code, e.g. using atexit, and many don't, either way how would you free the memory allocated in the above example in the clean-up code if it's scope is local to the function ini_lib ?

Comment: `void init_lib(){
    static char *buf=NULL;
    if (buf==NULL) {
       buf = malloc(18);
       ArrayList_add(MYLIBRARYS_UNIQUE_PREFIX_pointersToFree, buf);
    }
    .....
}` then in cleanup, go through MYLIBRARYS_UNIQUE_PREFIX_pointersToFree and free all of those pointers

Comment: yes, what I'm trying to say is that many libraries don't bother doing that because it's going to be free'd anyway when the program exits, so valgrind reports it as a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you need to run valgrind with --dsymutil=yes to get more useful information about leak location

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of osx you are running. But on the version i am running valgrind reports those errors as ignorable.